# Evenly space list items vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way with CSS to evenly space list items vertically.

I want each list item to have a fixed height that doesn't change.  I want the margin in between each list item to automatically strecth so it has the same amount of space but margin:auto; is not working.

Here is snippet:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}

.spaced {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.spaced li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="spaced">
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So with this snippet I need it so the blue boxes will remain the same height and be spaced evenly vertically.  If the black box changes in height then the blue boxes will still be evenly spaced.

How can I do this?

Comment: Go research `flexbox`, with that it is quite trivial. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox** and [`justify-content: space-around;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

> Flex items are evenly distributed so that the space between two adjacent items is the same. The empty space before the first and after the last items equals half of the space between two adjacent items.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.spaced {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0;
}
.spaced li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="spaced">
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
    <li>item </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you get this to work when the height of the container has a `min-height`?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}
.spaced {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.spaced li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="spaced">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery.

Here is the updated css,

```
 .container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
}

.spaced {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin:0; //Additional 
}
.spaced li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 370px; //Additional 
  float:left;   //Additional 
}
```

Js code is below,

```
   function setLiMargin(){
        var parentH = $(".container").height();
        var liCount = $(".container ul li").length;
        var liHeight = 60;
        var margin = parseInt((parentH/liCount - liHeight)/2);
        $('.spaced li').css('margin',margin+'px 15px');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
            setLiMargin();
    });
```